# How to set firebase landing page without the index.html showing on the link

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm currently making a website for an organization and trying to improve my SEO since the old website of the organization is overtaking the new deployed website on the search results. The organization I'm working for has currently no control over the old website so they can't remove it.

Our website link is philpolsci.com and it brings us to philpolsci.com/home whenever I enter the link. I want to put the home page on philpolsci.com without the /home on the link. The website only runs with javascript to function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect your website from the hosting services. You can follow the steps below to redirect your website from philposci.com/home to phiposci.com :

1. First you need to see where the option is available to redirect the website in your hosting service provider.
2. After that, you need to put the address philposci.com/home in the input field of the website that you want to redirect and the next input field to which you are redirecting your website such as philposci.com
3. After adding the addresses in the address bar, you can simply press on create redirect button.

As in my case, my hosting service provider is hostinger and I need to go in the domains section and then redirects sub-section where I will put the addresses of both the sites that I want to redirect.
[You can add the address in the redirect to as philposci.com and click on create redirect button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjndE.png)

For SEO purpose, you need to do the seo again of the newly created website.

Comment: I'm using Google Domains and can't seem to find any redirect settings. The only setting I find close to it is DNS Settings but I'm not sure what to do with it.